# Use rdf:ID in RDF/XML generated file

Tags: jena, rdf-xml

We generate a RDF/XML file which has all its resources with the `rdf:about` attribute. We would like to replace this attribute with `rdf:ID`.

Using apache-jena 3.17.0.

We create a resource with `model.createResource(uri,res)` where `uri` is an UUID with prefix `_` (`_04f2f0d3-10f4-4248-a7fc-fc8243ec7250`) and `res` is a resource from a vocabulary.

The resource node in the generated file has the `rdf:about` atribute. We like to have `rdf:ID` instead.

Comment: Discussion on users:@jena: https://lists.apache.org/thread/w4x0vpsypwg506t1tyq5nkbkmsmwgrnv

Comment: What is your [answerable programming question](/help/how-to-ask)?